# Cycles - 2.79 vs 2.82 texture difference

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have a simple example: image_textured cube. In v2.82 the cube is not textured if I choose cycles, however it works with Eevee. This worked in Blender v2.79. Am I missing something?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you have to set Cycles as the render engine in the Render Properties tab, then switch the viewport shading to 'Rendered'

Comment: OK, thanks, that solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use All for your Material Output node,

[image]

Since 2.82 provide the ability to **preview your scene** like what EEVEE does in Cycles mode, the shader is actually using EEVEE rendering information despite that you set Cycles as rendering engine. See the example below:

[image]